# Separate DB connections for magento session handler

Tags: php, magento

This post is regarding session management in magento. I have switch magento session management from files to database.

I want to store session related data in separate database to keep the load less on my magento database.I have read from different forums that session manager will use the same connection to read and write data that magento uses for their database.

Is there a way that i can define a separate connection_read and connection_write specifically for session handler.I am designing a site with almost 250,000 Sku and expect a lot of session related calls in database.

Thanks,
Ali.

Answer (score 1):

If your `default_write` and `default_read` are different databases and you are using `database` for session management in your local.xml Magento/Zend should be reading and writing specifically when storing the session data within the database being specified on reads/write specific logic.

From the sounds of it however, you may want to look into using memcached for your session storage as it does a very good job of decentralizing session storage among multiple servers.

http://blog.nexcess.net/2010/03/22/enabling-memcached-in-magento/

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/app/etc/local.xml.additional

Comment: I am specifically looking for storing sessions in separate database.

Comment: Does any one Know that it is possible to configure magento system to use separate database just for sessions management.

What i have read about it , magento database session handler uses same connection as uses by magento catalog database.

If any one knows that there is a way that magento database session handler be configured to use different database connection, share it with me. Thanks for the response by BOOMER.